# Making a constantly running background program with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I'm making a website and for brevity, it takes rows from a LocalDB file and puts them into a table. The table data is emails from a gmail account. I have a full console program that adds the new emails into a SQL Table, but I can't add new emails to the table since the .mdf file is already open with the ASP.NET MVC application. Is there any way to get around this, or is there a way to add a program that would run on a timer inside of the MVC application?

Comment: Have you tried yourself? Where is the source code? Share your code so we may be able to help you.

Comment: in this case i'd recommend adding an api in the MVC app to get the new rows (e..g have multiple apis). In general, though, localdb is very limited, and you should consider whether it is time to move to an actual SQL server.

Comment: [SQL Express supports multiple users](http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/sql-server-express-multiuser-capable). Can you be more specific about the problem or error you are encountering?